# Making ajax response global and usable in all routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, global-variables

I am writing a node js express api application which needs to a couple of ajax calls in the beginning of the application when it starts up and it needs to use this "global" data for all the requests it receives.

In the beginning of my app.js, I have

`var users = require('./modules/users');`

in my users.js, I make the ajax calls to retrieve my users.

```js
//ajax call 1
request.post({url:url1, formData: data}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {       
    //some code      and ajax call 2 
    request.get(url2, function(error, response, body) {         
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        var users = response.users;      // I want to make this users global and available in all routes           
    }).auth(null, null, true, access_token);  
});
```

My route looks like this

```js
router.post('/create', users.validate, function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}
```

and users.js is a module where I want access to the users list.

```js
var users = {
  validate: function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
      // Global variable
      var user_list; // This should be the response from the ajax requests
      
      var user_id = req.query.user_id;
        
      return user_list.indexOf(user_id) != -1
    }
  }
}

module.exports = users;
```

How do I make the `users` global so that I can use it in each route?
If there is an alternate better way of doing this, please suggest.

Comment: Can you not just put the initial declaration of `users` outside of this ajax request then simply access the variable from the global scope?

Comment: i tried adding. it returns users as undefined to me possibly because the ajax requests were not done. am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module for storing the user information. You can attain the functionality by simply using global variables in NodeJS, but I like this approach because its modular and extensible for checks and hooks down the development line.

Below is a simple example.

**user-store.js**

```
var userData = null;

module.exports = {
    setUserData : function (data){
        userData = data;
    },
    getUserData : function (){
        return userData;
    }
};
```

In your AJAX call, you can cache the store the data in the module by doing something like this as you need:

**users.js**

```
var userStore= require('./user-store');

ajaxCall()
  .then((response) => {
      var users = response.users;
      userStore.setUserData(users);
  });
```

To use the user data globally, you can import `user-store.js` and call `getUserData` function.

**wherever-you-need.js**

```
var userStore= require('./user-store');
var userData = userStore.getUserData();
```

Let me know if this approach serves the purpose for you.

Comment: thanks Prashant. This actually serves my purpose/requirement. Since I need to run the ajax calls when the app starts and won't use it until a request hits a route endpoint. However I am still curious if there is an alternate way to expose it to all routes globally

Comment: Can you update your question with code of your api routes so that I can see how you want to use the variables globally?